# is there a way to insert routes coming from api?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on a project where I have routes that should come from my API

I tried to do Route.config.unshift, it actually worked, but the route will only exists after the project is loaded.

I need it to work when the user didn't access my site at all, i needed to call my API before my app inits the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documented way is to use `resetConfig(routes: Route[])`

https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetConfig

What you could do is first add a `{ path: '**', component: LoadExternalRoutesComponent }`
and in that component you could use the http client to load the api, and then call the `router.resetConfig()`

The hard part will be to get angular and webpack (angular-cli) to create all the modules, and if you are using lazy loading that could be a problem.

There is a feature in the angular.json file called lazyModules which will force angular and webpack to create the modules even if they are not used.

```
"build": {
   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
   "options": {
      ...
      "lazyModules": [
         "src/app/lazy/lazy.module"
      ]
   }
   ...
```

I found this tutorial on the subject https://www.dzurico.com/angular-lazy-load-modules-with-cli/

I hope this will point you in the right direction